# objects that are not created show on the page, and redirect fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

I tried out rails 3, and just started a new project. The following is all I typed.

```
rails new todo
cd todo
bundle install
rails generate scaffold Task done:boolean task:text created:date
rake db:migrate
rails server&
firefox 0.0.0:3000/tasks&
```

On page `0.0.0:3000/tasks/new`, I filled in some values for the fields, and clicked the button to create a new `task`. It redirects to `0.0.0:3000/tasks` with a blank page. When I manually reload the page, it shows up eight `tasks` even though there is supposed to be only one.

When I further click either `show`, `edit`, or `destroy`, it says, for e.g.: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#show` `Couldn't find Task with ID=1`.

When I reload to `0.0.0:3000/tasks`, all eight `tasks` are still there.

What is wrong with this? Is rails corrupted on my computer?

**Log**

When I click 'create tasks', the terminal displays

> Started GET "/tasks/new" for 127.0.0.1
>   at 2011-05-13 22:04:26 -0400
>   Processing by TasksController#new as
>   HTML Rendered tasks/_form.html.erb
>   (6.7ms) Rendered tasks/new.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (25.3ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views:
>   27.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

folowed by something like this repeated eight times with `x` in `tasks/x` varying from `1` to `8`:

> Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2011-05-13 22:04:32 -0400   Processing
>   by TasksController#create as HTML
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"QZHWWyE5KcZhLrzRhB4Fgnl9HGiQqNkn17O4CUfUUJU=",
>   "task"=>{"done"=>"0",
>   "task"=>"test\r\n",
>   "created(1i)"=>"2011",
>   "created(2i)"=>"5",
>   "created(3i)"=>"14"},
>   "commit"=>"Create Task"}   AREL
>   (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("done",
>   "task", "created", "created_at",
>   "updated_at") VALUES ('f', 'test ',
>   '2011-05-14', '2011-05-14
>   02:04:32.065805', '2011-05-14
>   02:04:32.065805') Redirected to
>   http://0.0.0:3000/tasks/2 Completed
>   302 Found in 17ms [2011-05-13
>   22:04:32] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError:
>   the scheme http does not accept
>   registry part: 0.0.0:3000 (or bad
>   hostname?)
>     /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:746:in
>   `rescue in merge'
>     /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:743:in`
>   merge'
>     /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:163:in
>   `setup_header'
>     /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:101:in`
>   send_response'
>     /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:86:in
>   `run'
>     /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in`
>   block in start_thread'

Comment: What's does `development.log` show when you click "Create Task"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access your site using `0.0.0:3000` which is an invalid address (I'm actually surprised this even gives you access to the site at all).

Open `0.0.0.0:3000` in Firefox instead, and it will work perfectly!

(You can also use `localhost:3000` or `127.0.0.1:3000`)

Comment: dmarkow You are absolutely right. That was the case. Thank you. My problem was just a stupid mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I will use `localhost`. That will cause less trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Task is a reserved word in Rails. I guess thats the reason why rails is behaving in a starnge way.

For a list of other reserved words please refer to any of these links

http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rails_reserved_words/

http://www.yup.com/articles/2007/01/31/no-reservations-about-keywords-in-ruby-on-rails

http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of that. I tried it if different words, and now, I get seven duplicates instead of eight. So your point may have been one factor, but I still seem to have a problem.

Comment: My main production site has had a `Task` model and I've never had a problem with it before.